# InstallTool not accessible on TYPO3 v12.4 update

Tags: typo3

Trying to update an existing TYPO3 Version I stumbled accross a Problem with FormProtection.
We have our dev-envirment configured to use the NullBackend for caching. After Update neither the InstallTool nor the Backend is working anymore.

> TYPO3\CMS\Core\FormProtection\FormProtectionFactory::createForType(): Return value must be of type TYPO3\CMS\Core\FormProtection\AbstractFormProtection, bool returned

This is comming from here:

https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/3c9ad409dd55fe8ff6a003f927b7399e992d1ee4/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/FormProtection/FormProtectionFactory.php#L84

Disabling the use of NullBackend helps. But im wondering if this is expected behavior or an bug.

Related bug: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101635

Comment: Thanks for the post. Same issue with my instance after upgrading. I also had a line of code to avoid caching on DEV using that NullBackend in additionalConfiguration.php on my old TYPO3 11.x - this does not seem to work anoymore in 12.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code works to disable cache in TYPO3 LTS12, thanks to Benjamin Butschell.

```
foreach ($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'] as $cacheName => $cacheConfiguration) {
  if ($cacheName !== 'runtime') {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$cacheName]['backend']
        = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Backend\NullBackend::class;
   }
}
```

Comment: I consider this as a workaround, to still have "most" of the cache disabled. 
Seems to work for me like this. 
I will accept the Answer, but it has to be fixed in core, IMHO.